# Integrate LibOpenCL in android project

Tags: android, opencl

I would like to reuse a Android Eclipse project to use OpenCL library.
I used to setup my eclipse project for my previous phone a Samsung Alpha.
Now I get a moto Z and I would like to modify thgis project to reuse it.

I get the libOpenCL.so file from my phone and I juts change the file on my project but the compilation send me that error:

```
    [x86_64] SharedLibrary  : libJNIProcessor.so
/home/xxxx/NVPACK/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: jni/libs/libOpenCL.so: incompatible target
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1090: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseContext'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1099: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseCommandQueue'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1135: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseKernel'
jni/processor.cpp:143: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainProgram'
jni/processor.cpp:145: error: undefined reference to 'clGetProgramInfo'
jni/processor.cpp:147: error: undefined reference to 'clGetProgramBuildInfo'
jni/processor.cpp:152: error: undefined reference to 'clGetProgramBuildInfo'
jni/processor.cpp:156: error: undefined reference to 'clGetProgramBuildInfo'
jni/processor.cpp:159: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseProgram'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2878: error: undefined reference to 'clEnqueueWriteBuffer'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1106: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2548: error: undefined reference to 'clSetKernelArg'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1108: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1106: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2548: error: undefined reference to 'clSetKernelArg'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1108: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2548: error: undefined reference to 'clSetKernelArg'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2548: error: undefined reference to 'clSetKernelArg'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1106: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1108: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1106: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1108: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseMemObject'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:3248: error: undefined reference to 'clEnqueueNDRangeKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1144: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseEvent'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1090: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseContext'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1088: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainContext'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1090: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseContext'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1045: error: undefined reference to 'clGetContextInfo'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1099: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseCommandQueue'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1097: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainCommandQueue'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1099: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseCommandQueue'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2668: error: undefined reference to 'clBuildProgram'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2769: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1135: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1133: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1135: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2769: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1135: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1133: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2769: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1133: error: undefined reference to 'clRetainKernel'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1090: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseContext'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1099: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseCommandQueue'
/home/xxx/NVPACK/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-binary.mk:702 : la recette pour la cible « obj/local/x86_64/libJNIProcessor.so » a échouée
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1473: error: undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1480: error: undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1534: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateContextFromType'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2791: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateCommandQueue'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:2602: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateProgramWithSource'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1126: error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseProgram'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1037: error: undefined reference to 'clGetProgramBuildInfo'
jni/include/CL/cl.hpp:1855: error: undefined reference to 'clCreateBuffer'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Edit:
I remove all OpenCL program and I just set the OpenCL lib and I get that:

```
x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: jni/libs/libOpenCL.so: incompatible target
/home/xxxx/NVPACK/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-binary.mk:702 : la recette pour la cible « obj/local/x86_64/libJNIProcessor.so » a échouée
```

Edit 2:

I finally download the NDK10e (the one I used when I first compile this project) and the build works. But on the execution I get that error on log:

```
02-22 10:00:41.077  7302  7302 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.subsamplecamera, PID: 7302
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libGLES_mali.so" not found
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.subsamplecamera.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:30)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1100)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2551)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-22 10:00:41.078  7302  7302 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.ru
```

But I don't have mali GPU, why the project is calling mali library

Edit 3:
I finally made it, the program compile properly and the app run. 
I change the standart NDK10e to the Snapdragon LLVM and it seems to works.
Now I add a error during the executiong of the OpenCL kernel.:

```
gQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(gNV21Kernel,
                cl::NullRange,
                cl::NDRange( (int)ceil((float)w/16.0f)*16,(int)ceil((float)h/16.0f)*16),
                cl::NDRange(4,1),
                NULL,
                NULL);
```

I don't understand that error. Can someone help me about that?
    CL:: error -36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the problem may have caused as because :

- OpenCL on Android is not officially support by Google. Therefore, you
  may expect to see the OpenCL not supported on some Android devices.
  Though, so far, most of the flagship devices have the OpenCL support,
  such as devices with Qualcomm/Samsung chipsets (except Google Nexus
  devices, but there is workaround for some Nexus devices, please
  google online).
- If you clearly know your app will run only on certain devices, which
  support OpenCL, you can go ahead to do it. The OpenCL on Qualcomm and
  Samsung chipsets is pretty stable right now, and the compiler has
  been optimized for quite a few years; therefore, you can expect some
  good performance out of those devices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The OpenCL lib seems to be supported because on QualCOMM website there is adrenosdk with OpenCL files for my chipset but there are no complete project.

Comment: Can you share link where it is written that OpenCL lib is supported?

Comment: There are no page which tel that my moto Z support OpenCL lib but it is written that the Snapdragon 820 :https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/processors/820

Comment: You are right about your issue. I have found the same thing on that link. Let me dig this matter and will inform you.

Comment: Do you think it could comes from the ndk13b ?

Comment: do these : create the project again and check for the NDK path configuration

Comment: yes I can now definitely sat it is because of NDK. Are you using SDK also with NDK?

Comment: I try the NDK on a new projec, it works properly. It only bug when I try to add Opencl.

Comment: have you make sure that the path given for the NDK is correct? or the NDK is properly downloaded?